# How to fix my onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState?

Tags: java, android, screen-rotation, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I'm trying to save all the values & clicks from user during screen rotation, but my button click and text view isn't working. I've spent so many hours trying to figure out what to write inside this method and none of them worked. The input from Select your Tip button and textView output isn't being saved at the moment. [image: Image of App]

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: Started");
        String text = txtNumOfSplits.getText().toString();
        int no = Integer.parseInt(text);
        outState.putInt("count", no);

        String num_of_splits = txtNumOfSplits.getText().toString();

        //Convert String to Integer
        int no2 = Integer.parseInt(num_of_splits);
        outState.putInt("count", no2);

        money = Double.parseDouble(edtBillAmount.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("bill", String.valueOf(money));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: Started");

        String text = txtNumOfSplits.getText().toString();
        int no = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        txtNumOfSplits.setText(no + "");


        money = Double.parseDouble(edtBillAmount.getText().toString());
        String money = savedInstanceState.getString("bill");
        txtTotalBill.setText("Total Bill\n$" + finalAmount.toString());

    }

    btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_subtract = findViewById(R.id.btn_subtract);
    btn_20 = findViewById(R.id.btn_20);
    btn_15 = findViewById(R.id.btn_15);
    btn_10 =findViewById(R.id.btn_10);
    btn_calculate = findViewById(R.id.btn_calculate);
    btn_reset = findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);

    txtBill = findViewById(R.id.txtBill);
    txtTip = findViewById(R.id.txtTip);
    txtSplit = findViewById(R.id.txtSplit);
    txtRoundUp = findViewById(R.id.txtRoundUp);
    txtNumOfSplits = findViewById(R.id.txtNumOfSplits);
    txtTotalHeading = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalHeading);
    txtTotalPerPerson = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalPerPerson);
    txtTotalBill = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalBill);
    txtTotalTip = findViewById(R.id.txtTotalTip);
    txt_switch_error = findViewById(R.id.txt_switch_error);

    switchRoundUp = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchRoundUp);
    switchRoundDown = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchRoundDown);

    edtBillAmount = findViewById(R.id.edtBillAmount);

    horizontalLine = findViewById(R.id.horizontalLine);
```

Comment: Please add your XML layout and specify the view IDs that are not saved. Also, show the declaration of the finalAmount variable.

Comment: Hi @plplmax, can i reach out to u personally, I can send u the whole file, it's much easier that way.

Comment: It would be better if you edit this answer instead, because other people can learn from your experience :)

Comment: I would have, but the code is a bit private & confidential for me to post it here.

Comment: You don't need to publish the whole code, you can publish only the xml layout and specify the view IDs that need to be saved.

Comment: I've just updated it, you can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need? You can add double values parsing if necessary.

```
    private static final String NUM_OF_SPLITS_KEY = "num_of_splits_key";
    private static final String SELECTED_BUTTON_KEY = "selected_button_key";
    private static final String TOTAL_PER_PERSON_KEY = "total_per_person_key";
    private static final String TOTAL_BILL_KEY = "total_bill_key";
    private static final String TOTAL_TIP_KEY = "total_tip_key";

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: Started");

        String textNumOfSplits = txtNumOfSplits.getText().toString();
        int numOfSplits = Integer.parseInt(textNumOfSplits);
        outState.putInt(NUM_OF_SPLITS_KEY, numOfSplits);

        int selectedButtonId = 0;

        if (btn_10.isSelected()) selectedButtonId = R.id.btn_10;
        else if (btn_15.isSelected()) selectedButtonId = R.id.btn_15;
        else if (btn_20.isSelected()) selectedButtonId = R.id.btn_20;

        outState.putInt(SELECTED_BUTTON_KEY, selectedButtonId);

        outState.putString(TOTAL_PER_PERSON_KEY, txtTotalPerPerson.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(TOTAL_BILL_KEY, txtTotalBill.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(TOTAL_TIP_KEY, txtTotalTip.getText().toString());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: Started");

        int numOfSplits = savedInstanceState.getInt(NUM_OF_SPLITS_KEY);
        txtNumOfSplits.setText(numOfSplits + "");

        String selectedButtonId = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_BUTTON_KEY);

        if (selectedButtonId == btn_10.getId()) selectButton(btn_10);
        else if (selectedButtonId == btn_15.getId()) selectButton(btn_15);
        else if (selectedButtonId == btn_20.getId()) selectButton(btn_20);

        String totalPerPerson = savedInstanceState.getString(TOTAL_PER_PERSON_KEY);
        txtTotalPerPerson.setText(totalPerPerson);

        String totalBill = savedInstanceState.getString(TOTAL_BILL_KEY);
        txtTotalBill.setText(totalBill);

        String totalTip = savedInstanceState.getString(TOTAL_TIP_KEY);
        txtTotalTip.setText(totalTip);
    }

    private void selectButton(@NonNull Button button) {
        button.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm currently getting an error saying that cannot find symbol variable outState from these 3  
        outState.putString(TOTAL_PER_PERSON_KEY, txtTotalPerPerson.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(TOTAL_BILL_KEY, txtTotalBill.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(TOTAL_TIP_KEY, txtTotalTip.getText().toString());

Comment: Actually I fixed it myself. Just had to replace outState with savedInstanceState.
Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: But I think there's a bug in the round up & down switch, bc the app just abruptly crashes.

Comment: @ryan, sorry for ignoring it for a long time. What exception occurs after a crash? Is there a stack trace with a line of code where an exception occurs?

Comment: no worries, I've already submitted the assignment anyway.